# How do I enable users to submit sessions in "Conference Organizing Distribution"?

Tags: 7

I don't see any configuration item or link that would enable logged-in users to submit sessions in the [Conference Organizing Distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/cod) module. How can I enable this? What link should I use?

I'm using the latest module version for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out. It's as simple as going here as a logged in user: https://example.com/node/add/session